# Linearizability vs. Serializability

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, shared-memory, consistency

From [this](http://www.bailis.org/blog/linearizability-versus-serializability/), I understand that

- Linearizability and Sequential Consistency are for Single Operation on Single Object
- Serializability and Strict Serializability are for Multiple Operations on Multiple Objects.

Does single operation on single object mean the following?

> Sequence 1:
>
> T1:
>   Read(X) Write(X)
>
> T2:
>   Write(X) Read(X)

Whereas multiple operations and multiple objects mean:

> Sequence 2:
>
> T1:
>   Read(Y) Write(X) Read(Y)
>
> T2:
>   Write(Y) Read(X) Write(Y)

Does this also mean that:

1. Sequence 2 can reason about the execution of functions (or methods in java)?
2. Sequence 1 can ONLY reason about a subset of operations on the same object within the function?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note that consistent histories---according to a given consistency model, such as linearizability or serializability---are defined as those that satisfy *sequential specifications* of objects with respect to the points of operation (or method) invocations [1, 2].

More specifically:

> sequential specification for an object is just a set of sequential histories for the object

where history is defined as:

> a finite sequence of method invocation and response events

where pair of invocation and response events form a method call, i.e.:

> a method call in a history H is a pair consisting of an invocation and the next matching response in H

Thus, indeed, linearizability is defined for single operations on single objects, but the definition can covers histories over multiple objects as well [1, 2]. On the other hand, serializability covers histories with multiple operations on multiple objects inherently, since it is (usually) defined in the context of transactional processing, where each transaction can involve multiple operations on multiple objects.

The two, namely single operations on single objects and multiple operations on multiple objects, can be made equivalent through defining methods on objects (that potentially unify multiple objects) that define appropriate *sequential specification* in which whole transactions are viewed as methods on some objects (e.g. a simple example is queue enqueue/dequeue [1]). This, in turn, defines the sequential specification of such objects, and thus valid histories according to given consistency models.

Now, if T1 and T2 are interpreted as threads, then indeed, sequence 1 invokes operations on single object, while sequence 2 clearly invokes multiple operations and multiple objects. Note that in both cases, histories can be checked with respect to both the linearizability and serializability, while read and write operations might be grouped into "semantically" atomic methods as discussed previously.

As per relationship between linearizability and serializability, serializability is strictly weaker consistency model in which valid histories might be equivalent to executions of methods in arbitrary sequences, while linearizability can be viewed as equivalent to strict serializability (if we view transactions as methods of a single object). Note that some authors started using linearizability in the context of transactions [3].

---

[1] [The Art of Multiprocessor Programming](http://store.elsevier.com/The-Art-of-Multiprocessor-Programming-Revised-Reprint/Maurice-Herlihy/isbn-9780123973375/). By Nir Shavit and M P. Herlihy

[2] [Linearizability: A Correctness Condition for Concurrent Objects](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~christoff/files/Linearizability-ACorrectnessConditionForConcurrentObjects.pdf). By M P. Herlihy and J M. Wing. ACM Transactions on Programming Languages and Systems, Vol. 12, No. 3, July 1990.

[3] [Software Transactional Memory](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/tds/papers/Shavit/ShavitTouitou.pdf). By Nir Shavit and Dan Touitou. Distrib. Comput. (1997) 10: 99-116.